# How restart memcached from PHP

Tags: php, memcached, centos

I have vps-hosting with centos. On this server are Apache, PHP, MySql.
I installed memcached.
And sometimes (once in 3-4 days) memcached stopping - I don't know why, in log file missing necessary information.

I found that solution - every 10 minutes run cron, which verify started or not memcached (through command memcached-tool), when memcached already crashed -
i send e-mail and through server command line start memv=cached

But i would start memcached automatic, but i can't do this.

I tried so command

```
system("/etc/init.d/memcached start");
exec("service memcached start");
system("service memcached start");
```

but i haven't result.

Comment: memcached no goode! trie rnning root php user or chnge php usr to root for work it!

Answer (score 4):

I want to just point out that it is much safer to create an actual cronjob for things like this.

Please read more on the `exec()` function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Additionally, if `safe_mode` is on, you won't be able to execute commands outside of your `safe_mode_exec_dir`. These are set in `php.ini` or a custom php configuration.

As another answerer has noted, it would be better to isolate the cause of the crash instead of repeatedly starting it. What kind of errors are you getting when memcached crashes? Obviously you have some way of knowing it has crashed, otherwise you wouldn't be asking the question. The most obvious answer could be that the cache has filled up and your scripts are hitting the cache too hard/often for it to page out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use sudo to make php escalate to root before killing and starting memcached or you'll get permission deined.

P.S. try to check why memcached crashes instead of restarting it!!

Comment: I changed sudoers through visudo, but i have the same result.

I unserstand that right way is find cause crashing memcached, but my log file is empty.
Below is memcached config
PORT="11211"
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="2048"
CACHESIZE="1000"
OPTIONS=""
LOGFILE="/var/log/memcached.log"

gsgsd

Answer (score -1):

You would probably need to use sudo. The user running apache is not allowed to run the init script itself.

```
system("sudo /etc/init.d/memcached start");
```

Will probably have enable the apache user to use sudo. this is done via visudo command. http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/visudo.man.html

But honestly better would be to use something like monit, to automate the 'watchdog' role. Its designed for it. http://mmonit.com/monit/

Comment: I changed sudoers through visudo, but i have the same result.

Comment: it didn't work for me too may be for safe_mode is on, i need to check though.